# Where clause for aliased column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which parses a string values from a column:

```
SELECT left(DateTimeSent, 17) AS timesent FROM allog_07_11_e query1
```

When I do:

```
SELECT left(DateTimeSent, 17) AS timesent FROM allog_07_11_e query1.timesent != '0'
```

I get:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'timesent'.
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: As to why you can't use in `WHERE` clause an alias defined in the `SELECT` list, it's due to the: [order of execution of a `SELECT` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685)

Answer (score 5):

You can't reference an alias in the `WHERE` clause.  You'd have to do something like this:

```
select left(DateTimeSent, 17) as timesent
from allog_07_11_e
where left(DateTimeSent, 17) <> '0'
```

Likewise, you could also use a subquery:

```
select *
from
(
    select left(DateTimeSent, 17) as timesent
    from allog_07_11_e
) a
where timesent <> '0'
```

Comment: `You can't reference an alias in the WHERE clause` - Not entirely true - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You **CAN** reference an alias if you define it with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT timesent 
FROM allog_07_11_e query1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT left(DateTimeSent, 17)) CxA(TimeSent)
WHERE timesent <> '0'
```

Comment: Touche, my friend.  +1 for the corner-case.  I don't see this as a viable option for the OP, but nevertheless you did find a way!

Comment: @Shark I only really use this when I need to derive other calcs from calcs.  It really simplfies say making a calculation based off another average or something.

Comment: Nah. You are cheating :). The cross apply is sub-query. It is just a bit different from the one posted by @Shark.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I wouldn't count it as a subquery since there's no `FROM` in it!

Comment: Ahh. Yes, I see that this could turn into some kind of philosophical discussion. For me it is the presence of the `SELECT` that makes it a query.